# Find the Earliest Date in Excel

Tags: excel

i want to find the earliest date between the DOB OF FATHER & DOB OF MOTHER in sheet1, by matching the employee code and having the value in earliest date in sheet 2.

Sheet 1

```
Employee Code   DOB OF FATHER      DOB OF MOTHER
28883               29/12/1987      28/01/1988
83933               19/11/1988      12/07/1988
55428               21/01/1938      03/10/1938
99999               18/03/1982      11/02/1980
```

Sheet 2

```
Employee Code   Earliest Date
28883   
99999   
83933   
55428
```

Comment: You seem to have misclassified your sheets -- the question says 1 and the sample data says the opposite.

Comment: i Have made the corrections.. Thank You..

Comment: So, there will be multiple rows with `Employee Code`  like  `28883` in Sheet 1?

Comment: No only one row with one unique value. no repeated value. Same in sheet 2 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sheet1:
        A       B            C
    1   Code    FatherDOB    MotherDOB
    2   28883   29/12/1987   28/01/1988
    3   83933   19/11/1988   12/07/1988
    4   55428   21/01/1938   03/10/1938
    5   99999   18/03/1982   11/02/1980

Sheet2:
        A       B
    1   Code    EarliestDOB
    2   28883   29/12/1987
    3   99999   11/02/1980
    4   83933   12/07/1988
    5   55428   21/01/1938
```

You can combine two `vlookup` operations with a `min` operation:

```
=MIN(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$5,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE))
```

The first `vlookup` gives you the father's date of birth (using the *entire* table range but extracting the second column) and the second gives you the mother's date of birth (extracting the third column).

The earliest is then simply the minimum of the two.

---

If some of the dates may be blank, the easiest solution is probably to set up a `D` column on sheet 1 to evaluate the earliest date, ignoring blanks. For example `D2` would have (split across lines for readability):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),
    B3,
    IF(ISBLANK(C2),
       B2,
       MIN(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$C$5,2,FALSE),
           VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE))))
```

If one of the cells is blank, it uses the other, otherwise it chooses the earliest.

Then you just lookup that new column `D` in the formula on sheet 2 (example for `B2`):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$5,4,FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi.. the formula is working for the 1st 3 employee code, however for the 4th Employee code i.e 55428 it is showing the wrong date.

Comment: @PrasanthRamakrishnan, yes, forgot to mention that form of `vlookup` requires sorted data so you'll need to sort on sheet 1 first. Alternatively (and this is probably a good idea anyway), add the fourth parameter `FALSE` for an exact match.

Comment: Hi, thanks its worked when sorted. Is there any formula where the same result can be achieved without sorting ?

Comment: Hi, Employee 28883 should return the value 28/01/1988 which is earliest date, however it is returning 29/12/1987. Please check about that.

Comment: @PrasanthRamakrishnan, in what universe does 1988 come before 1987? :-) If you mean to use only the day of the year for comparisons (rather than the whole birthdate), you'll need to modify the items returned by `vlookup` before choosing the minimum.

Comment: what would be the formula in case for a particular employee code there is no DOB FOR FATHER, in that case DOB FOR MOTHER needs to be taken into consideration. However for me it is showing as 00/01/1900.

Comment: @PrasanthRamakrishnan, in that case, I would add a D column to sheet1 with `=IF(ISBLANK(B2),B3,IF(ISBLANK(C2),B2,MIN(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$C$5,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE))))` and then just `vlookup` on that. I'll add it to the answer but any further stuff should really  be a separate question so as to not clog up the comments, and to get more answers than just mine.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point out a limitation that has been in Excel forever.

Excel internally doesn't handle dates before 3/1/1900 (March 1, 1900) correctly.

- it thinks that 1900 was a leap year
- that the day before 3/1/1900 is 2/29/1900
- if you enter pass Excel through automation any date between 12/31/1899 and 2/28/1899, it will think it is 1/1/1900 - 2/29/1900
- if you attempt to pass it through automation 12/30/1899, it will think it is January 0, 1899.
- if you attempt to pass it any date before 12/30/1899, it will throw an error

Various example dates that you can pass to Excel through automation:

```
Date     Excel
-------- ------------------------------
18651001 throws error going into Excel
18991201 throws error going into Excel
18991229 throws error going into Excel

18991230 shows as "12:00:00" in Excel; it refuses to show a date portion

18991231    shows in Excel as 1/1/1900
19000101    shows in Excel as 1/2/1900
19000102    shows in Excel as 1/3/1900
19000103    shows in Excel as 1/4/1900
19000201    shows in Excel as 2/2/1900
19000228    shows in Excel as 2/29/1900
19000229    Feb 29 1900 was not a real date; Excel takes it

19000301    shows in Excel as 3/1/1900
19000601    shows in Excel as 6/1/1900
19001231    shows in Excel as 12/31/1900
19010101    shows in Excel as 1/1/1901
20151128    shows in Excel as 11/28/2015
```

The [VARIANT structure does dictate that a date must be after December 30, 1899 midnight as time zero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237601.aspx):

> ## 2.2.25 DATE
>
> DATE is a type that specifies date and time information. It is represented as an 8-byte floating-point number.
>
> This type is declared as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef double DATE;
> ```
>
> The date information is represented by whole-number increments, starting with December 30, 1899 midnight as time zero. The time information is represented by the fraction of a day since the preceding midnight. For example, 6:00 A.M. on January 4, 1900 would be represented by the value 5.25 (5 and 1/4 of a day past December 30, 1899).

tl;dr: If you have any dates in Excel before March 1 1900 (e.g. the birthdate of the oldest woman alive), Excel will not perform the math correctly.

If you wish to display any date before 3/1/1900, it should be presented as **text**, rather than an actual date.

Anyone attempting to find the *minimum* date in a range needs to be aware of this limitation in Excel.